# How to mock .map function?

Tags: scala, mocking, mockito

Let's say I need to mock this:

```
List().map(doSomething)
```

I tried to find an answer on the internet but didn't find a solution

Comment: Why mock data if data can be passed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mocking `.map` makes no sense - you are working on pure data, so if you want to change result, you change the input. It would be like mocking `.substr` or `.toLowerCase` in `String`.

Especially since `.map`, `.flatMap` and friends are interfaces with contracts - you wouldn't mock `.equals` and `.hashcode` because you would have to reimplement contracts with mocking API where passing data would give you that for free.

And this is what `List`, `Set`, `Free`, `IO`, etc are - data. You don't mock data, you mock behavior - objects with managed state and side effects. That's why nobody described how to do it.